# Generating Running Sum of Ratings in SQL

Tags: postgresql, sum

I have a rating table. It boils down to:

```
rating_value  created
+2            april 3rd
-5            april 20th
```

So, every time someone gets rated, I track that rating event in the database.

I want to generate a rating history/time graph where the rating is the sum of all ratings up to that point in time on a graph.

I.E. A person's rating on April 5th might be `select sum(rating_value) from ratings where created <= april 5th`

The only problem with this approach is I have to run this day by day across the interval I'm interested in. Is there some trick to generating a running total using this sort of data?

Otherwise, I'm thinking the best approach is to create a denormalized "rating history" table alongside the individual ratings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have postgresql 8.4, you can use a window-aggregate function to calculate a running sum:

```
steve@steve@[local] =# select rating_value, created,
                              sum(rating_value) over(order by created)
                       from rating;
 rating_value |  created   | sum 
--------------+------------+-----
            2 | 2010-04-03 |   2
           -5 | 2010-04-20 |  -3
(2 rows)
```

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS

Comment: That is badass and exactly what I need.

Comment: @araqnid i've a related question which is likely to get closed if i were to ask on SO. what would you recommend: 1) creating a separate aggregateRatings table that gets updated with every new rating; 2) calculate aggregate ratings run time; I'm more inclined to do the first option, but skeptical about triggers, specially across shards.   I will highly appreciate your suggestion. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try to add a group by statement. that gives you the rating value for each day (in e.g. an array). as you output the rating value over time, you can just add the previous array elements together.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll just do this. I was hoping there might be some kind of automagical RUNNING_SUM() function that meant I didn't have to do any post-processing of the result, but it's trivial anyway.

Comment: You may want to take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/rolling_sums_in_mysql.html